# How to limit display items on data filter of Portfolio, BOOTSTRAP 3

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a data filter which i want to only display a limit of at least 12 of the items but, suddenly i cannot do it, which requires me to click the button first for the function to filter, I want not to display all the items, just want to display at least 12 of it, this is my code:

```
<ul class="portfolio-filter">
                <li><a class="btn btn-primary active" href="#" data-filter=".products">Products</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".services">Bootstrap</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".medicines">HTML</a></li>

            </ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->
```

and for the items:

```
<ul class="portfolio-items col-4">

                <?php

                            $prodalbum = mysql_query("select * from product") or die(mysql_error());

                                while ($prodalbum_row = mysql_fetch_array($prodalbum)) {
                                          $prodname = $prodalbum_row['product_name'];
                                          $image = $prodalbum_row['prod_image'];
                                          $description = $prodalbum_row['product_description'];

                            ?>
    <li class="portfolio-item products">
        <div class="item-inner">
           <div class="portfolio-image">
                <img src="<?php echo "super_admin/$image"; ?>" alt="">
                   <div class="overlay">
                <a class="preview btn btn-primary" title="Products" href="<?php echo "super_admin/$image"; ?>"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  
                </div>
                        </div>
                        <h5>Products</h5>
                    </div>
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
        <?php 
                            } ?>


                <li class="portfolio-item services">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item2.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item2.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>         
                    </div>
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                <li class="portfolio-item services">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item3.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item3.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>        
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>          
                    </div>           
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                <li class="portfolio-item medicines">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item4.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item4.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>          
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>        
                    </div>           
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                <li class="portfolio-item medicines">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item5.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item5.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>          
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>  
                    </div>       
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                <li class="portfolio-item services">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item6.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item6.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>           
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>         
                    </div>           
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                <li class="portfolio-item medicines">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item5.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item5.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>          
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>  
                    </div>       
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                <li class="portfolio-item medicines">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="portfolio-image">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/item6.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="images/portfolio/full/item6.jpg"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>           
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>        
                    </div>         
                </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
            </ul>
```

but all the items are displaying if i dont click on button filter function, what should i do?